# Apply formula only to cells where another cell matches criteria

Tags: excel

I have a checklist in Excel and want to check if each "group" is "ok", and set "Total" to be "ok". There are multiple columns for different "projects" (P1 and P2 in my example).  Column E is an example where Total would be "ok", if each row below it would be true, but that would require a new column for every project so I had hoped there would be another solution like an array formula.

```
    | A    | B     | C  | D  | E
----+------+-------+----+----+
 1  | Name |       | P1 | P2 |   Example
----+------+-------+----+----+
 2  | Total        | ok |    |   =IF(AND(E4:E10);"ok";"")
----+------+-------+----+----+
 3  |      |       |    |    |
----+------+-------+----+----+
 4  | Group A      | ok | ok |   =OR(ISEMPTY(A4);C4="ok")
----+------+-------+----+----+
 5  |      | Sub 1 | ok | ok |   =OR(ISEMPTY(A5);C5="ok")
----+------+-------+----+----+
 6  |      | Sub 2 | ok | ok |   =OR(ISEMPTY(A6);C6="ok")
----+------+-------+----+----+
 7  |      |       |    |    |   =OR(ISEMPTY(A7);C7="ok")
----+------+-------+----+----+
 8  | Another Head | ok |    |   =OR(ISEMPTY(A8);C8="ok")
----+------+-------+----+----+
 9  |      | Arm 1 | ok |    |   =OR(ISEMPTY(A9);C9="ok")
----+------+-------+----+----+
 10 |      | Arm 2 | ok | ok |   =OR(ISEMPTY(A10);C10="ok")
----+------+-------+----+----+
```

My current idea is to check if the cell in column A is empty or if there is "ok" in column C (or D etc.) for each cell. Basically something like `{=AND(OR(ISEMPTY($A4:$A10);C4:C10="ok"))}`.

Comment: Could you please post an example of the input and the expected output? I think it would help the question to be more specific.

Comment: This is the example? The input is the lines below and the output should be Total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,"Group*")=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"Group*",C:C,"ok"),"ok","")
```

[image]

And you can extend the formula to the right, and add new groups without needing to change the formula.

Basically checks if the number of groups equals the number of groups with "ok".

Comment: I've updated my example, because I cannot count on it being `Group*`, but `*`works just as well, as long as I constrain the search area like `$A4:$A100` (unfortunately there is no `$A4:$A` afaik) and do the same with `C:C`.

Comment: @xZise Ah in that case yea. Or if you keep the data and the totals in separate sheets, that would be easier in that regards.